# "TypeError: 'set' object is not callable"

Tags: python, macos, amazon-web-services, ipython, typeerror

I have two iPython notebook installations. One on an AWS Micro Instance, the second using Anaconda on my Macbook (OS X Yosemite).
I encountered a difference in the way both of them handle the following code:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 10, 11, 1, 5]
your_list = [1, 2, 3, 0, 12, 13]
my_set = set(my_list)
your_set = set(your_list)
print my_set
print len(my_set)
print len(my_list)
```

On iPython-AWS, my output is:

```
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 11])
7
9
```

On iPython-Macbook, my output is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-cd060f1b0bde> in <module>()
      1 my_list = [1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 10, 11, 1, 5]
      2 your_list = [1, 2, 3, 0, 12, 13]
----> 3 my_set = set(my_list)
      4 your_set = set(your_list)
      5 print my_set

TypeError: 'set' object is not callable
```

Additionally, these are the installation details, if relevant:
1. iPython on AWS Micro Instance: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYrq8.png

2. iPython Notebook on Macbook - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Id5.png

I cannot seem to find the reason for this difference, although I did come across many threads on Stackoverflow regarding the "TypeError: 'set' object is not callable" issue.
I will appreciate any help in understanding why this is so, and if there is anything I can do to ensure my code runs on both installations.

Comment: What is python version in both of these cases?

Comment: if you `print set` at the start of the code what do you see?

Comment: 2.7.6 on the AWS Version.
2.7.10 on the Local version.

Comment: And this happens if you input the code shown, exactly, *immediately* upon starting up Python fresh? And you can demonstrate that with a screencap?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried `print set` as suggested. It's been running for about 2 mins on AWS. Locally, this was the result:
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-51947dbe83cc> in <module>()
      1 my_list = [1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 10, 11, 1, 5]
      2 your_list = [1, 2, 3, 0, 12, 13]
----> 3 my_set = set(my_list)
      4 your_set = set(your_list)
      5 print set

TypeError: 'set' object is not callable`

Comment: I mean just `print set` as soon as you start ipython

Comment: Do `print set` on the ipython-macbook (where you are getting the error)

Comment: Of course, it is useless to try to `print set` as a diagnostic at a point in the code **after** the exception is raised**. Try it **before** you do anything else.

Comment: Thanks, I started a new notebook, and ran it afresh and the code is working.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This error indicates that you may have defined a set with the variable name as `set` , if you did so, that would overwrite the `built-in` function `set` .

Example of this issue occuring -

```
>>> set = set([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> my_set = set([2,3,4,5,6])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'set' object is not callable
```

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted. I would bet real money that some variation on this is what happened.

Comment: Thanks - this might be the issue, I will look closer at the code and find the relevant line.

Answer (score 2):

You can restart the kernel in the top menu.
Kernel->Restart

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove any predefined variable you have assigned, may be intentionally or unintentionally & the error will be vanished.
I have wrongly `placed = sign` between print statement & brackets like `print=(A|B);` due to which it was happening.
After clearing print variable it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
my_set = set

my_set.update(my_list)
```

Do not use brackets.

Comment: I assumed you meant `my_set` and `my_list`, which is what is used in the OP's example code.

Answer (score 0):

[FIXED]

TypeError: 'set' object is not callable

As we know set is a 'built-in function'

you just add (del set) before you assign any variable and run the program

P.S : later you can remove it.

Example:

```
tuple_data = {'A','B',1, 2, 'B','A'}
#del set
var_1 =  set(tuple_data)
print(var_1)
type(var_1)
```

output:

```
{1, 2, 'B', 'A'}
set
```